# Korma not loading JDBC correctly

Tags: clojure, korma

I would really like to use Korma for my project, but every time I try to test it in my REPL, it throws the following error:

```
core=> (require 'korma.db)
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/java/jdbc/internal__init.class or clojure/java/jdbc/internal.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:432)
```

I have the following in my 'core' namespace:

```
(ns core
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]))
```

and the following in my project.clj:

```
(defproject wknd "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "weekend side project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
             [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
             [org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.7.2"] 
             [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.2.2"]
             [korma "0.3.0-beta9"]]
  :dev-dependencies [[org.clojars.scott/lein-nailgun "1.1.0"]])
```

I am just starting out on clojure and have no idea why I'm getting this error. I've searched around and couldn't find similar issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the author:

> Korma hadn't been upgraded to the latest JDBC since the reorganization
>   of it. Try beta11, should be fixed.
>
> Cheers, Chris.

and this error disappeared for me.